# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout, RecyclerView en blanco

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter

Mi problema es que me aparece en blanco mi recyclerView, al ver el log me aparece el error " E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout", he intetado solucionarlo viendo otros post sobre esto pero aun no lo pude solucionar. Sé que tengo que mover alguna linea que estoy declarando con anterioridad, pero no se cual.
Si me ayudan a identificar cual, les agradecería.

acá va mi Main activity

```
 RecyclerView recyclerViewRowset;
MyApiAdapter myApiAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    recyclerViewRowset = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerViewRowset.setAdapter(myApiAdapter);


    /*user = findViewById(R.id.Usuario);
    contraseña = findViewById(R.id.Password);
    prueba = findViewById(R.id.prueba);

    prueba4= findViewById(R.id.prueba4);*/

    informeConexion = findViewById(R.id.conexionActivity);
    prueba3 = findViewById(R.id.prueba3);


}

public void Prueba(View v){

    recyclerViewRowset = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerViewRowset.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(" http://137.116.116.34:91/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    Conexion conexion = retrofit.create(Conexion.class);

    Cuerpo login3 = new Cuerpo("xxx", "xxx", "xx");
    Call<LoginUser> call2 = conexion.getUser(login3);
    call2.enqueue(new Callback<LoginUser>() {

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginUser> call, Response<LoginUser> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();

            if(statusCode == 200) {
                informeConexion.setText("code: " + response.code() + " Conexión exitosa " + "\n");


                Mq0302aDatareq contactList =  response.body().getMq0302a();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OUTPUT : "+response.body(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("MainActivity", "posts loaded from API");
                //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OUTPUT : "+response.body().getContacts(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                    Log.d("MainActivity", "posts loaded from API");                 List<Contact> contactList =  response.body().getContacts();                    for(int i = 0; i<contactList.size(); i++)
                for(int i = 1; i<contactList.getRowset().size(); i++) {
                    String tableId = contactList.getTableId();
                    int moreRecords = contactList.getRecords();
                    boolean records = contactList.getMoreRecords();



                    ArrayList<Rowset> rowset = (ArrayList<Rowset>) contactList.getRowset();
                    String cliente = rowset.get(i).getCliente();
                    int home = rowset.get(i).getCantidad();
                    int office = rowset.get(i).getOrden();
                    prueba3.setText("Cliente: " + cliente  + "\n" + "Cantidad: " + home + "\n" +"Orden: " + office + "\n");

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OUTPUT : "+statusCode +", "+ tableId +", "+ moreRecords +", "+ records +",¨ " + cliente +"," + home +","+ office , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    myApiAdapter = new MyApiAdapter(rowset, this);

                    //MyApiAdapter myApiAdapter;


                  /*  prueba.setText("Cliente: " + cliente  + "\n" + "Cantidad: " + home + "\n" +"Orden: " + office + "\n");
                    prueba3.setText("Tabla: " + tableId  + "\n" + "moreRecords: " + moreRecords + "\n" +"records: " + records );*/

                }

            }else {
              //  prueba3.setText("code: " + response.code() + " Conexión fallida " + "\n");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR " + statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        MyApiAdapter myApiAdapter;
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginUser> call, Throwable t) {


            // prueba3.setText("problema: " +t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });

}
```

mi adaptador

```
 private ArrayList<Rowset> recyclerDataArrayList;

 public Context mcontext;



 private static Conexion API_SERVICE;

    public static Conexion getApiService() {

        // Creamos un interceptor y le indicamos el log level a usar
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        // Asociamos el interceptor a las peticiones
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

        String baseUrl = "http://137.116.116.34:91/";

        if (API_SERVICE == null) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build()) // <-- usamos el log level
                    .build();
            API_SERVICE = retrofit.create(Conexion.class);
        }

        return API_SERVICE;
    }

 public MyApiAdapter(ArrayList<Rowset> recyclerDataArrayList, Callback<LoginUser> mainActivity) {
     this.recyclerDataArrayList = recyclerDataArrayList;
     this.mcontext = mcontext;
 }


 @NonNull
 @Override
 public MyApiAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
     View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup,false);
     return new ViewHolder(view);
 }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyApiAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {


     //ArrayList<Rowset> modal = (ArrayList<Rowset>)recyclerDataArrayList;
     viewHolder.tv_name.setText(recyclerDataArrayList.get(i).getNroCliente());
     viewHolder.tv_version.setText(recyclerDataArrayList.get(i).getCliente());
     viewHolder.tv_api_level.setText(recyclerDataArrayList.get(i).getOrden());

 }

 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {

        return recyclerDataArrayList.size();
 }


 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
     private TextView tv_name,tv_version,tv_api_level;


     public ViewHolder(View view) {
         super(view);

         tv_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
         tv_version = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_version);
         tv_api_level = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_api_level);



     }
 }
```

}

y agrego mi XML, quizas el error esta ahi

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/conexionActivity"
    android:layout_width="162dp"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:hint="Estado de la conexión"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.034" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="116dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="Prueba"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="381dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.493"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.277" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/prueba3"
    android:layout_width="316dp"
    android:layout_height="428dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

y acá el LOG

*.ConscryptPlatform$platformTrustManager$2>
2022-03-23 14:44:18.664 13773-13773/com.example.finalvm I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$platformTrustManager$2>
2022-03-23 14:44:18.721 13773-13773/com.example.finalvm **E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout**
2022-03-23 14:44:19.628 13773-13773/com.example.finalvm D/MainActivity: posts loaded from API
2022-03-23 14:44:19.729 13773-13800/com.example.finalvm D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf034d60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaf039470)
2022-03-23 14:44:19.827 13773-13800/com.example.finalvm V/RenderScript: 0xb41a6e00 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
2022-03-23 14:44:23.135 13773-13800/com.example.finalvm D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf034d60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaf039470)*

Answer (score 0):

Una causa de :

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Es que los datos que el ArrayList que usas para instanciar el Adapter, en este caso  `rowset`, se encuentre vacío.

```
myApiAdapter = new MyApiAdapter(rowset, this);
```

Comment: sabes que lo pensé en un momento eso, pero a aplicarlo en un setText, me devuelve información  `                  /*  prueba.setText("Cliente: " + cliente  + "\n" + "Cantidad: " + home + "\n" +"Orden: " + office + "\n");
` pero me devuelve info asi que quise plasmarlo tambien en un arraylist

Comment: Si imprimes rowset.size() antes de definirlo en el Adapter obtienes resultados?

Comment: intenté imprimir  rowset.size y se me cerró la aplicacion, tenes razon ahi hay algo que no esta funcionando, pero me parece raro que aplicarlo en un maketext si aparezca.

Comment: El problema seguramente es que no tiene valores , debes asegurar que la petición responda con los resultados.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ahora sé por donde ir!

Comment: sabes que volví a tirar el size de rowset y ahora me aparece (https://ibb.co/PCYcQKY), pero aun sigue sin aparecer el arraylist